# (Python) Blocking sub-process

Tags: python, subprocess, pyodbc

I have a script class that queries from a database and displays the result. the problem is when i add a sub process below the script, the script hangs (or waits, and will continue if terminate with ctr-c)

eg. Group A will run if Group B is deleted. Group B will run if Group A is deleted

```
#Group A
queryStrings = ['SELECT top 100 * FROM myDb', 
'SELECT top 10 * FROM anotherDb']

## class that connects to db and output the content ## 
db = Database
conn = db.connectToDb()

for query in queryStrings:
     db.runPreQueries(conn, query)

conn.close

##Group B 

if os.path.exists("DoSomething.vbs"):
    p = subprocess.Popen("cscript DoSomething.vbs", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()

print("vbs completed")
```

I also tried using subprocess.call, and then terminating it. This wont hang but it doesn't execute the script

```
p = subprocess.call("cscript DoSomething.vbs")
p.terminate()
```

Comment: what does `"cscript DoSomething.vbs"` when run from the console? does it exit?

Comment: yes it does exit. its just a simple echo

Comment: First I would try `p = subprocess.Popen(["cscript",'DoSomething.vbs"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`. Do you need the output? do you need to pass the input?

Comment: yes it works when group A is removed. i don't need the output and i don't need to any inputs, i just need to execute it.

Comment: `conn.close`, shouldn't it be `conn.close()` ? that's probably your problem.

Comment: yes this is the issue, thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when running `conn.close` you're not really closing the database. It does nothing because you're not calling the function.

So next call stays blocked waiting for database access.

Fix:

```
conn.close()
```

note that the proper way of running your process afterwards is (since you don't care about input, output, ...):

```
subprocess.check_call(["cscript","DoSomething.vbs"])
```

this will just fail if `cscript` returns a non-zero return code, which is safe enough.

Note that your database interface probably supports context manager, in that case, it would be better to write:

```
with db.connectToDb() as conn:    
    for query in queryStrings:
         db.runPreQueries(conn, query)
```

in that case, connection is closed automatically when exiting the `with` block.